# problem on automorphism and stabilizer

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is finite group whose order is divisible by the prime $p$ and $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $G$ s.t. $\sigma^p$ is the identity. Show that $G$ has an element $g$ of order $p$ with $\sigma (g)=g$

**attempt 1**: Orbit-stabilizer theorem

$\{\sigma^k\mid k\in \mathbb{N}_p\}$ acts on $X\subset G$. $p=\mid orb(g)\mid  \mid stab(g)\mid$, $g\in X$. For $g$ s.t. $\circ (g) \neq p$, the above equation is probably useless. So a good choice is $X=\{g\mid \circ(g)=p\}$. Still, this equation is probably useless.

**attempt 2:**

$\phi (g)=g^{-1}\sigma (g)$. T.p. $\exists g$, $\circ(g)=p$, s.t. $\phi (g)=e$. Since $G$ is finite, one way is to prove $\phi$ is injective hence surjective. But $\phi$ is not injective.

Please give a hint. Please do not give solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DerekHolt why "This has order divisible by $p$"? At least please tell whether the Burnside's lemma is used or not. Haven't studied it.

Comment: No you don't need the Burnside Lemma. Since $\sigma^p=1$, the orbits of $\sigma$ on $G$ all have length $1$ or $p$. Since $|G|$ is divisible by $p$, so is the total number of orbits of length 1.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt 1 is close.

Let $A=\{\sigma^k\ |\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by assumption.

Now $A$ acts on $G$ via $(\tau,g)\mapsto \tau(g)$. By [the Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) we have

$$|G/A|=\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{\tau\in A}|G^\tau|$$

i.e.

$$p\cdot |G/A|=\sum_{\tau\in A}|G^\tau|$$

Of course $G^\text{id}=G$ and so $p$ divides $|G^\text{id}|$ by assumption. Therefore $p$ divides $\sum_{\tau\in A\backslash\{\text{id}\}}|G^\tau|$. And since $|A\backslash\{\text{id}\}|=p-1$ then $|G^\tau|>1$ for at least one $\tau\neq\text{id}$. In particular there is $g\neq 1$ and $\tau\neq\text{id}$ such that $\tau(g)=g$. And since $\tau$ generates $A$ (every non-trivial element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a generator) then $\sigma(g)=g$. Obviously $g$ is of order $p$ since $\sigma$ is.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't learn the Burnside's lemma. Also, @DerekHolt's comment works.